# Does progeny born out of varNa-SaMkara (intermixing of classes) also derive gotra from father?

Tags: caste-system, gotra

There was an episode where SatyakAma Jabala of unknown lineage was accepted as a disciple. Similarly, the recent, there happened another incident where King Prasenadi from the lineage of shAkhya was convinced by revered Gautam Buddha to accept his son as shAkhya only when the later was found to be conceived by a woman of 4th class unknowingly. These two episodes are dealt with in this article names [The Buddha was every inch a Hindu](http://indiafacts.org/the-buddha-was-every-inch-a-hindu/)

> He predicted the coming of a future awakened leader like himself, the
> Maitreya (“the one practicing friendship/charity”), and specified that
> he would be born in a Brahmin family. **When King Prasenadi discovered
> that his wife was not a Shakya princess but the daughter of the Shakya
> ruler by a maid-servant, he repudiated her and their son; but his
> friend the Buddha made him take them back.**
>
> Did he achieve this by saying that birth is unimportant, that “caste
> is bad” or that “caste doesn’t matter”, as the Ambedkarites claim? No,
> **he reminded the king of the old view (then apparently in the process
> of being replaced with a stricter view) that caste was passed on
> exclusively in the paternal line. Among hybrids of horses and donkeys,
> the progeny of a horse stallion and a donkey mare whinnies, like its
> father, while the progeny of a donkey stallion and a horse mare brays,
> also like its father. So, in the oldest Upanishad, Satyakama Jabala is
> accepted by his Brahmin-only teacher because his father is deduced to
> be a Brahmin, regardless of his mother being a maid-servant.** And
> similarly, King Prasenadi should accept his son as a Kshatriya, even
> though his mother was not a full-blooded Shakya Kshatriya.

So what this article is saying is progeny invariably derive its gotra from its father lineage irrespective of the fact varNaSaMkara happened or not which was supported by Buddha.

Is this claim supported or deduced by scriptures? This question indirectly asking - what gotra to assign to the progeny born out of intermixing of classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a child invariably derives Gotra from its father irrespective of it being product of varNa-saMkara. From [Manu SmRitI 10.64](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201799.html),

> > śūdrāyāṃ brāhmaṇāj jātaḥ śreyasā cet prajāyate | 
> >  aśreyān śreyasīṃ jātiṃ gacchatyā saptamād yugāt || 64 ||
>
> If the child born from a Śūdra woman to a Brāhmaṇa goes on being
> wedded to a superior person,—the inferior attains the superior caste,
> **within the seventh generation**.—(64)

What it tells is that the taint of varNa-saMkara withers away & the progenies of 6th generation (or before) from progeny out of varNa-saMkara eventually brings about unconfused progeny belonging to one of the pure 4 varNa if the children born out varNa-saMkara are wedded to one of the caste while ensuring to not let varNa-Samkara happen again in successive generation. Such generation also obtains all the rights of its varNa.

Therefore, the possibility of 6th (or lessth) generation from a confused forefather (from 6th or less generation back) becoming full-fledged unconfused generation belonging to one of 4 varNa implies that their forefather had derived Gotra despite being progeny of varNa-Shamkara.

Answer (score 1):

In Gita,Arjuna says to Sri Krishna :

> (1.38 1.39) O Janardana, although these people, whose hearts have become perverted by greed, do not see the evil arising from destroying the family and sin in hostility towards, friends, yet how can we who clearly see the evil arising from destroying the family remain unaware of (the need of) abstaining from this sin?
>
> (1.40) From the ruin of the family are totally destroyed the traditional rites and duties of the family. When rites and duties are destroyed, vice overpowers the entire family also.
>
> (1.41) O Krsna, when vice predominates, the women of the family become corrupt. O descendent of the Vrsnis, **when women become corrupted, it results in the intermingling of castes.
> (1.42) And the intermingling in the family leads the ruiners of the family verily into hell. The forefathers of these fall down (into hell) because of being deprived of the offerings of rice-balls and water.**

Bhagavan Sri Krishna does not say anything against this, which means He is of the same opinion (**maunam sammatilakshanam**).

He also Himself says that Varna-shakaras destoy the world:

> •3.24 **These worlds will be ruined if I do not perform action. And I shall become the agent of intermingling of castes, and shall be destroying these beings.**

**I think it means that the Varnasankaras are fallen and has no gotra. Otherwise, they would not have been deprived of the dharmik duties like pindadaana.**

Comment: Silence doesn't always imply acceptance Sir...

Comment: Krishna do implies in BG 2.1-5 - "O Parth, it does not befit you to yield to this unmanliness. Give up such petty weakness of heart and arise, O vanquisher of enemies." ... I think Krishna meant Arjuna was involved in overthinking & was giving flabbergasted [slippery slopping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slippery_slope) arguments. Neverthless, varNaShaMkar is devastating but I am not sure how it affects bloodline. Blood should remain same.

Comment: @Mr.Sigma., what do you mean by 'Blood should remain same'?

Comment: @ram progeny although mixed will have blood of his father.

Comment: @Mr.Sigma. Sri Krishna does think Varnashankara is dangerous.Pl see my update: Gita 3/24

Comment: Is it applicable to vyasa ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi, it is not applicable to avatara purushas. Besides, their union was accepted - Anuloma (Brahmana male, Kshatriya female).

Comment: @ram so if a brahmin does menial jobs still considered brahmin?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi, if he does menial jobs because of emergency times/situation,then yes, he is still brahmin. But if over time, he has given up the desire for upanayana/vedas/gayatri, then no. The very fact that he has gotten brahmana janma in this birth means he has some punya credit left in his karma bank. till that gets exhausted he has chance to redeem his varna.

Comment: @ram no she was doing Fisher woman job since early age. Moreover the progeny was born outside of wedlock.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi, who made weddings auspicious ? Not you or me, right? The same Bhagavan who gave auspiciousness to wedlock, gave auspiciousness to Parashara & Satyavati & Veda Vyasa. He is avatara purusha. Our mortal rules don't apply to them.

Comment: @ram what reference?  You are bringing hypothesis