# Do the Vedas mention mixed-castes (Varṇa Saṅkara-s)?

Tags: vedas, caste-system, varna

The famous *Purūṣa Sukta* doesn't mention *Varṇa Saṅkara-s*. Kṛiṣṇa also didn't talk about *Varṇa Saṅkara-s* despite of concerned raised by Arjuna,

> adharmābhibhavāt kṛiṣhṇa praduṣhyanti kula-striyaḥ 
> strīṣhu duṣhṭāsu vārṣhṇeya jāyate **varṇa-saṅkaraḥ** - BG-v1.41

though Kṛiṣṇa went on to mention & talk about four varṇa-s. The literal meaning of *Varṇa-Saṅkara* is corruption of Varṇa, not loss of Varṇa, as if some amount of sand has been mixed with soil. Moreover, as discussed [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32639/does-progeny-born-out-of-varna-samkara-intermixing-of-classes-also-derive-gotr/45089#45089), the taints of *Varṇa-Saṅkara* could wither away from society within 7 generations if successive generations are taken care in particular ways (i.e, the sullied soil due to mixture with sand could also be made unsullied). Therefore, it reduces us with only 4 varṇa-s— either pure or impure ones.

So, I wonder if *Varṇa-Saṅkara-s* have been mentioned in the Vedas? I'm quite aware of several names of the *Varṇa-Saṅkara-s* mentioned in Smṛiti-s, Mahābhārata, etc. but I am specifically looking for their mentions in the Vedas.

---

<sub>I mean with Varṇa-Saṅkara-s, here, by progenies out of mixture of castes.</sub>

Comment: Going through the works of Kumarilla Bhatta and Bharuci, I'm surprised to find so many "Puranic" and "Smartic" injunctions in the Vedas themselves. So I'm positive that you will find reference to varna-sankara in Vedas.